# Run Build command in React is giving me Error: Invalid Mapping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, build, tailwind-css

I keep getting this error when I run "npm run Build". I.m making use of React and Tailwind CSS

Failed to compile.

static/css/main.fe47aa2f.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":4,"column":16607},"source":"static/css/main.fe47aa2f.css","original":{"line":723,"column":null},"name":null}

Comment: Same here with CRA 5 and TW 3. I think column should not be `null`.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem and filed a bug report here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7687

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in `postcss`. I'm able to build successfully by force downgrading `postcss` to 8.4.5 in `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "postcss": "8.4.5",
    ...  
  }
```

See also https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1724